# What are the residual consequences of having an adsense account application denied?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I am about to apply for an adsense account so I can display ads for a new website/web app I have built. It is My first experience with adsense and I have heard that quite often adsense applications are rejected.

The nature of the website is genuine content/software and I believe any reasons for the application being rejected would be minor technical quibbles rather than some fundamentally unfixable problem with the nature of the website or its content.

My question is, if I apply and get rejected - on some issue that is fixable - will I be able to simply fix issue (to adsense's satisfaction), re-submit the application and then get approved - or are there permanent consequences to having failed an application one or more times?

Comment: As far as I know, this should not be a problem. Google wants to make money too. The number one reason for being turned down is that the site is too small and the content not significant enough to be considered attractive. Make sure you develop your site and app fully and have enough to compete in search and be relevant before applying for adsense. Do not jump the gun on this and you should be okay.

Comment: thanks @closetnoc. so basically after policies etc, the question adsense ask is: *will this site/app actually reach a significant audience with attractive features/content - such that it would be financially worthwhile for all parties involved* ? I know content quality is subjective, but is there any recommended figures about what is "big enough" or how many visitors per month you are getting - before you submit an application?

Comment: I wish I had numbers for you. I would say it is more of a feeling. When you have reached a point that you are really proud of what you have produced and are sure that people will be influenced by it, then you are ready. I am not sure it is a monetary thing as much as many of the sites we have seen here that have been rejected were simply not at all mature and far too thin that visitors would be pleased to have found the site. If visitors would link to your site and share it socially, then you are probably ready.

Comment: ok well I better keep improving then! , good advice and well explained thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no "consequences" to being rejected by Google. It is uncommon for Google to reject the request to create an adsense account, so I would not worry about it.

To insure your are accepted, I strongly suggest you review the Adsense program policies listed here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en